# Deduction of Kinetic energy operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, differentiation

In Chapters 1 and 2 of *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* Third edition, Griffiths and Schroeter state that to get kinetic energy operator one replaces momentum with $p\rightarrow -i\hbar\,\partial/\partial x$ in kinetic energy expression.

But

$$K=\frac{p^2}{2m}\rightarrow-\frac\hbar{2m}\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}\right)^2\neq-\frac\hbar{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)$$

However, they define the second term to be kinetic energy operator instead of the first expression. Why is that?

Comment: What is $(\partial_x)^2$ supposed to mean if not $\partial^2_{x^2}$?

Comment: @TobiasFünke, same difference between velocity squared and acceleration.

Comment: @TobiasFünke This is an operator we are concerned with. Define an operator $T=\partial_t$. Now velocity squared is $(T(x))^2$ and acceleration is T(T(x)). The same difference that i am pointing out by $\neq$ is original post

Comment: @TobiasFünke I am not sure i get your point. x is the function here. $T(x)^2)$ is telling you to take derivative of x wrt t and square the result you get. $T(T(x))$ tells you to take derivative of x wrt t and take derivative of this thing wrt to t again. Both giving different results

Comment: You are confusing many things. As I said, it is standard notation to write $T^2:=T\circ T$ for any (linear) operator on some Hilbert space. What you say is indeed true: $(\partial_{x^2}^2f)(x)\neq (\partial_x f)(x)^2$, but no one is arguing for that. Instead, I say that it is standard to write $\partial^2_{x^2 }=(\partial_x)^2$, indicating repeated application of the derivative, just as the answer points out.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Ah, i get it now. Indeed notation wise you are correct. But my point is that why we define energy as second derivative wrt x and not derivative wrt x squared? (in the actual math speak and not notation that you refer to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In operatorial language for any operator $A$, $A^2$ means $A \circ A$, that is $A$ composed with itself. In the particular case of $A = \hat{p} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$, indeed
$$\hat{p}^2 = -\hbar^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\,.$$

As I was reading in your comment you wanted also a reason for why using the square of the $p$ operator is the correct way to apply the correspondence principle to the energy. I feel like any motivation will end up with some sort of "because it works" in the end so I may just give some examples and showing that $p^2$ does what you would expect the square of momentum to do. For example take an eigenfunction of the momentum operator $\phi_p(x)$ (I am avoiding Dirac's notation because I am not sure you have encountered it yet), that is
$$\hat{p} \phi_p(x) = p \phi_p(x)\,.$$

A particle described by the wavefunction $\phi_p(x)$ has definite momentum with the value $p$. Clearly than also the value of the square of momentum is well definite and it is $p^2$. The operator $\hat{p}^2$ is precisely the operator that satisfies the eigenvalue equation
$$\hat{p}^2 \phi_p(x) = p^2 \phi_p(x)$$
as you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

Once a differential operator represents the momentum $p$, $p^2 f$ should be intended as the operator $p$ acting on $pf$. Therefore, the second expression is the correct one.

---

*Edit after some exchange of comments*

Probably the key point to eliminate doubts as those raised in the question is that quantum mechanics (QM)  and classical mechanics are theories aimed at describing the time evolution of the state of a system and how observable quantities can be evaluated knowing the state.

There are equivalent ways to implement such a description. The Hilbert space representation introduces a dual framework: on the one hand, states are described in terms of the elements of a Hilbert space. On the other hand, observables are represented by operators on the Hilbert space of the states (well, there are some technical subtleties, but I neglect them since I would like to give the overall picture). In the case of usual spinless particles, such representation is based on an algebra of operators generated by the position $q$ and momentum $p$ operators obeying the following commutation rule:
$$
[q,p] = i \hbar.
$$
All the observables that in classical mechanics are functions of $p$ only are represented by the same function of the operator $p$. Therefore, the kinetic energy is represented by the operator
$$
\frac{p^2}{2m}.
$$
If we choose the Hilbert space of the square-integrable functions of the position $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$, the representation of the momentum operator is
$$
p = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$
and the operator representing the kinetic energy must be
$$
\frac{p^2}{2m}=- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.
$$

Comment: That makes sense. But how do we motivate this reasoning physically? I believe one can do it in terms of dimensional analysis but is there any other way?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Once we have a physical motivation for representing momentum and position as operators, no other step is required. The square of any operator means that that operator is applied twice. Dimensional analysis cannot help because the two operators in your formulas have the same physical dimensions.

Comment: I meant that once you apply the operator, call it p, to a quantity with dimensions, call if f, then dimensions of $p(p(f))$ will not be equal to dimensions of $(p(f))^2$

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist I agree, but there is no rational basis for introducing $(p(f))^2$. It is the algebra of the operators ($p$) that must reflect the algebra of the observables, not the algebra of the states transformed by operators ($p(f)$).

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Finally, I  think I have understood the origin of your doubts, and I have added an explicit explanation. It is a complement to the explanation given by lucabtz.

Answer (score 1):

Actually mathematical part of kinetic energy derivation is Ok :
$$ \begin{align}
 \hat T &= \frac {\hat p^2}{2m}\\
&=\frac {1}{2m}\left(\hat p \cdot \hat p\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2m}\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cdot -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2m}\left(-\hbar^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2m}\left(-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)
\end{align} 
$$

because $(\cdot)$ operator doesn't work as a simple arithmetic multiplication between variables $x,y$ here. Because our "variables" are of special kind,- quantum mechanical operators, which are functionals. And so multiplication rather work as a function composition $g(f())$ operator.